# How to create a schedule webJob to run a exe using CRON expression

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

There is a azure function(pre-release) which timely executes a windows service application.
Now I have to migrate it to a Azure webjob.

How can I write a webJob which schedules to execute the exe every 1 min using a [CRON Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression)

I am a complete newbie for WebJobs and I have no idea on how to do it. I'm using Visual studio 2015. Installed the Azure SDK 2.9.6 on top of that. I went through [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs) which says to

> simply include a settings.job file at the root of your WebJob zip
>   file. This JSON file should include a schedule property with a CRON
>   expression

But I coudn't figure out how I could do it in my Visual Studio solution, since in the WebJob I have created in Visual Studio, only has 'Functions.cs' and 'Program.cs'

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways to do it.

1. Set up a triggered WebJob and [schedule it using a chron expression in the settings.job file](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#user-content-scheduling-a-triggered-webjob).
2. Set up a continuous WebJob and schedule it using a [TimerTrigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger). Note that this involves adding Azure WebJob SDK Extensions, where option #1 does not.

Answer (score 1):

Rob Reagan's answer was informative. I found [this post](http://blog.jongallant.com/2016/01/azure-ondemand-to-scheduled-webjob/) with the visual studio example